# How to use separated password entity to prevent user from updating password with old used

Tags: symfony, authentication

I want to create a custom authentication system by separating passwords from user entity . each user can have more than a password and the latest one is used , and when user try to updated his password i want to prevent him to use an old password  , as like as it is described in the link bellow .
Please i need your help and thank you . 
https://filebin.net/wa6jrfy0t0xcqru7/Screenshot_from_2019-04-14_00-46-20.jpg?t=n9vnajox

Comment: Not sure what is being asked.  Normally you would just save the older hashed passwords somewhere and if password_verify matches a new password then you say nope nope nope.

Comment: Yes i have used this solution and it is working perfectly . thank you

Answer (score 0):

For me is not a custom authentication system, you just need to change the body of the method `getPassword`. you will find below an example.

`password.php`

```
<?php

namespace your\name\space;


use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use DateTime;

class Password
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="your\name\space\User", inversedBy="passwords")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     *
     * @var User
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="inserted_at", type="datetime")
     * 
     * @var DateTime
     */
    private $insertedAt;
}
```

`User.php`

```
<?php

namespace your\name\space;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

class User implements UserInterface
{

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="your\name\space\Password", mappedBy="user")
     * @ORM\OrderBy(value={"insertedAt" = "DESC"})
     *
     * @var Collection
     */
    private $passwords;

    /**
     * User constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->passwords = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        if ($this->passwords->isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        return $this->passwords->first();
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem is that i want to prevent user from using his old passwords , so in the password update i should iterate over the passwords array collection to check if the new password is one of them , and i didn't find a way to do that .

Comment: you only have to encrypt the new password and check if it exists in the collection `$passwords`